# I've made a bootstrap 5 navbar but it's not expanding when I make it a small screen, works for middle size (iPad screen dim), is this a common issue?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So the code below is for Django hence the blocks for the links, they work fine it's just when the screensize is too small the drop down nav doesnt drop down and if i leave it dropped down and make the screen smaller then I can't make it un drop down. Very annoying because I've got the website looking actually nice for once but it does this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="/">Company</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#nav" aria-label="Expand Navigation">
                <div class="navbar-toggler-icon"></div>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block home %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block pricing %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Pricing </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block how %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">How it Works </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block work %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'work' %}">Work With Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block contact %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Log In</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `navbar-expand-lg` to `navbar-expand` class on `<nav>` tag.

"lg" is for larger devices based on responsiveness.

You can check doc here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

So your code should be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="/">Company</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#nav" aria-label="Expand Navigation">
            <div class="navbar-toggler-icon"></div>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block home %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block pricing %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Pricing </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block how %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">How it Works </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block work %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'work' %}">Work With Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block contact %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: HI thanks for your reply, I tried this but it still faces the problems for smaller screens, the reason the lg there is so that when the screen is a certain size then it has the expandable navbar, that part works perfect it's just when it's too small it's like the expandable navbar button is turned off... not sure if this is a bug with bootstrap considering the code is relatively simple and doesn't seem to be an obvious flaw. EDIT: Just removed the rest of the content from the page and I no longer get this flaw, so maybe it is something to do with the items in the page...

Answer (score 0):

Add **aria-expanded="false"** on button

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="/">Company</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false aria-label="Expand Navigation">
            <div class="navbar-toggler-icon"></div>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block home %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block pricing %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">Pricing </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block how %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'index' %}">How it Works </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block work %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'work' %}">Work With Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link {% block contact %}{% endblock%}" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```